# Audio/Video out of sync in rendered video

Tags: video, audio

I've looked at some similar problem descriptions on this, but mine is slightly different. 
When I edit a music video with several cut scenes, in VSE the audio/video will be in sync on each cut until I play the video from the beginning.
When I do this, the video will slowly start to lag behind the audio getting further behind the longer I let it play. BUT if I manually click on a cut halfway through the video, it will be in sync again in VSE.
If I render the video, it acts just as it did when I play the video from the beginning in VSE, the video slowly starts to lag behind.
I did check all of the frame dropping/AV-sync settings, and I have those all enabled.
I was running 2.74, but I tried updating to the latest version and I'm still having the same issues.

Any suggestions would be great, as I've spent many hours getting this video ready and I don't want to have to scrap it.

The video is from a GoPro Hero 4 and is MP4 H.264 codec

Comment: Zoom out on the sequence editor so you can see the audio and video clips from your camera.  Are they the same length?

Comment: If the audio and picture's sync is drifting is most likely that you have a framerate for the project that is different to that of the footage.

Comment: Also try generating a proxy timecode for Blender to sync the media to. If the timecode is not enough then generate a proxy as well.

Comment: Try using mpeg4 container instead of avi for rendering

Answer (score -1):

What you need is *AV Sync*. *AV Sync* makes sure that your audio and video play together by dropping frames to match the audio. What you were experiencing before is your computer not being able to combine and output all the inputs for each frame in the amount of time it was given (<sup>1</sup>/<sub>30</sub> or <sup>1</sup>/<sub>24</sub> of a second).

*What you probably currently have:*

[image]

*Good:*

[image]

Comment: I have that enabled though.

Comment: The AV sync option is for playback in UI.  The OP's question is referring to an out of sync render.